# How to put the footer at the bottom of the visible page?

Tags: html, css

I am changing the Openx implementation and I added a footer. It is always in the bottom and if the page is too long, you need to scroll down to see the footer. But what I am trying to do is, putting the footer in the bottom of the visible part. You know like they put annoying banners right in the bottom and even when you scroll down or up, it is still there. I don't know the name of it. Right now, the footer is in  at the bottom. Not inside a div so it is always in the bottom. But, is there a way to make it position exactly the size of the page's visible part? My English is not enough to tell you what I mean I think. I am having some trouble with English right now. Any ideas about how to do that? This is the footer's css;

```
 .footer{
    position: relative;
    margin-top:-100px;
}
```

and it is placed like

```
<body>
    some divs..

    <div class="footer">
    </div>

</body>
```

should I put the footer in one div above? I tried it but it didn't work. Maybe the position should be relative to page's visible height?

Comment: To the right of your question there are some posts listed in the `Related` section. The first one is `How do you get the footer to stay at the bottom of a Web page?`. Will possibly solve your question

Comment: the suggested questions I looked sticks the footer at the bottom. But I guess what I mean is putting the footer at the bottom on the screen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try the folllowing css

```
.footer{
    width:100%;
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0px;
}
```

And make sure your footer div is the last div.

The position fixed makes your footer stay at the same place even if the browser window is scrolled

Comment: Thank you it worked. I also found a website which has what I want and when I looked at it with firebug, it is the same as yours! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what do you want to achieve.

But if you want your footer always at the bottom of the page try this:
http://jsfiddle.net/dV44J/

```
.footer{
width: 100%;
height: 50px;
position: fixed;
bottom: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, too. But I excluded the height.