# Button-groups at the bottom in differents devices

Tags: html, css, button, mobile, device

I am doing a design for mobile and I have to think in differents devices. I put a button-group in bottom of the page. It's means the bottons appear at the final of the scroll-bar. But, when the page its too small because the device is big, the bottons appear at the middle of the page. And after that, there is white space. 
I try with this rules: [How to put the footer at the bottom of the visible page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9189928/how-to-put-the-footer-at-the-bottom-of-the-visible-page) But the buttons appear always at the bottom of the screen. I need see the bottons after using scroll-bar.

**HTML**

```
<div id="botoneraInternet" class="btn-group btn-group-justified" role="group" aria-label="...">
    <div class="btn-group btn-group-lg" role="group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="botonHardware" disabled="" style="background-color: rgb(48, 144, 184);">
            <span><img class="icons" src="imagenes/llave.png"></span> Hardware
        </button>
    </div>

    <div class="btn-group btn-group-lg" role="group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="botonClose" style="background-color: rgb(223, 228, 229);">
            <span><img class="icons" src="imagenes/valija.png"></span> Cerrar WO
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.btn-group {
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.btn-group-justified {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-collapse: separate;
}
```

Someone can help me? 
Really thanks, and I am going to give the star to the best answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this....there wasn't enought code you provided so I improvised a bit. But let me know if this is what you need.

http://codepen.io/carinlynchin/pen/WvbLXE

CSS:

```
body{
    height:900px;
    position:relative;
}

.btn-group {
    position: absolute;
    width:100%;
    bottom:0
}

.btn-group div {
    display:inline;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="botoneraInternet" class="btn-group btn-group-justified" role="group" aria-label="...">
    <div role="group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="botonHardware" disabled="" style="background-color: rgb(48, 144, 184);">
            <span><img class="icons" src="http://barkpost-assets.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/grumpy-dog-11.jpg"></span> Hardware
        </button>
    </div>

    <div role="group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="botonClose" style="background-color: rgb(223, 228, 229);">
            <span><img class="icons" src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/3540744128/7dd80644ae052f1b04180c41bbc674ab.png"></span> Cerrar WO
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I try that but it doesnt work. This is a screen capture of the issue:
http://www.mediafire.com/view/dbm3c353sir8ww4/captura%2001.png?ssl=on

Comment: can you share the entire code? maybe replicate it in codepen.io or jsfiddle, because I would need to see the entire tree in order to see why its happening

Comment: sorry i had deleted the prior pen... here it is again

http://codepen.io/carinlynchin/pen/bdNzBK

Comment: ok, so maybe you need to add height:100% to outer containers...maybe one of them ends right there, so it is indeed at the bottom, except that parent doesn't extend the full height.

Comment: I can't put the full code, because there is js that charge this part and another that charge the following, and another... Its an old proyect that I am editing now. I try your way, but doesnt work. :(

Comment: pretty much you are going to have to look at how the dom is laid out. If the parent is the outerbox, then absolutely position it with bottom=0; but if there is another dom element in between, it's height could be affecting your positioning....or sometimes margins and padding can affect it too (remove all margin and padding to see if its the cause...if not, then check the height of elements in between the outer container and the buttons container ... then finally check inside the button container also)